# "Global" control visible on multiple pages?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this progressbar control which i would like to be visible on several pages of my application. How to i create a "global" control like this?

Thanks

/Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few questions:

- What do you mean by global?
- Would you like to create one instance
  of your progressbar and share it?
- What kind of control do you use? Is it [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?
- Are you aware of this [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)?
  If not:

I assume that app shows the progressbar when user is downloading or app is doing work in background. Make a Popup to show it to the user. You can put it in the Resources Dictionary, and then dynamicly add it to visual tree. But wont gain any advantage.

It is not a good idea to have one control if your app is based on default navigation system(pages). I strongly advise you to use progressbar form the toolkit. Simply create an instance for each page.

Comment: Well, i guess there is no shortcut to it. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you could create a page which includes this progressbar and then show/hide/etc. as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for doing this:

a) create a Popup element in code without making it part of the element tree and assign your control as child of that Popup. Then use IsOpen=true to show it.

b) retemplate the PhoneApplicationFrame that is the root of your element tree and insert your global elements in the part of the template that is shared across all pages.